# Does Windows Powershell have a Try/Catch or other error handling mechanism?

Tags: powershell, scripting, try-catch

In a script, when a command-let or other executable statement errors out, is there a try/catch type of mechanism to recover from these errors? I haven't run across one in the documentation.

Comment: Note to future readers: PowerShell v2 is out now and supports Try/Catch/Finally.

Answer (score 8):

You use a `Trap [exception-type] {}` block before the code you want to handle exceptions for.

Comment: +0 The real answer is now try/catch in PowerShell v2 and later as noted in the comment on the question. I +1d t@Mark Ingram instead as I consider this a dup that doesnt add much. (Yes I know this was a long time ago but I missed the comment on the question first time round and this was the highest voted)

Answer (score 7):

I've written about this in my TechNet Magazine column (technetmagazine.com, if you're interested).

First, PowerShell v2 will have a standard Try...Catch, which is great.

The existing shell (v1) has support for trap {} constructs. These must be defined prior to the exception happening. Also, most cmdlets require an -EA "STOP" parameter in order for them to generate a trappable exception. Traps can be defined in any scope, and will "bubble" up until trapped or until they hit the global (shell) scope.

At the end of a trap, execute Continue to return to the next line of code in the same scope as the trap, or execute Break to leave the current scope and toss the exception up.

Answer (score 2):

Here's someone (Adam Weigert) who implemented try/catch/finally using powershell.  I use this in place of the built-in trap staement.  Seems more natural.

http://weblogs.asp.net/adweigert/archive/2007/10/10/powershell-try-catch-finally-comes-to-life.aspx